# Mongoose MongoDb Will Not Run .save()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My first attempt to save a document. but it's not saving. I don't get any errors. I verified with `cpu.timeStamp` that the document object is getting created successfully and there is also a `cpu.save()` function. But for some reason the `cpu.save()` is not running at all because none of the console.log statments print inside that function. Also, when I go into the mongo shell `db.cpu.find()` is not returning any documents.

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
//var models = "./models";
//fs.readdirSync(models).forEach(function(file) {
//    require(models+file);
//});

var Cpu = require('./models/cpu.js');

function saveCpu(cpuResult) {
    var cpu = new Cpu ({
        timeStamp : cpuResult.timestamp,
        avaiable : cpuResult.available,
        status : cpuResult.status,
        metrics : [ { duration : "15m",
                      data : cpuResult.metrics["15m"].data,
                      type: cpuResult.metrics["15m"].type,
                      unit: cpuResult.metrics["15m"].unit
                    },
                    { duration : "5m",
                        data : cpuResult.metrics["5m"].data,
                        type: cpuResult.metrics["5m"].type,
                        unit: cpuResult.metrics["5m"].unit
                    },
                    { duration : "1m",
                        data : cpuResult.metrics["1m"].data,
                        type: cpuResult.metrics["1m"].type,
                        unit: cpuResult.metrics["1m"].unit
                    }]
    });

    //FUNCTION DOESN'T SEEM TO RUN AT ALL
    cpu.save(function (err, product, numberAffected) {
        if (err) { console.log(err) }
        console.log(product);
        console.log(numberAffected);
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you called `mongoose.connect` to actually connect to the server?

Comment: I bet that is it. How come it did not return a error message for that?

Comment: Yeah, that catches a lot of people.  It's because Mongoose will queue up any calls that are made before the connection is open to simplify start-up.